# How can I check if a DLL uses P/Invoke (DllImport)?

Tags: c#, pinvoke, .net-assembly

Given a DLL, how can I make sure it does (or does not) use P/Invoke, with a command line tool?

Comment: What is the true intent here?  That the .NET assembly accesses _any form of native code?_   If so don't forget native COM.  Even though Microsoft's _Dependency Walker_ may highlight COM dlls exports of 4 functions, they are generally not called directly via callers to create an object and have nothing to do with invoking it.

Comment: @MickyD COM is indeed next on my list. (I have already asked about unsafe code: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72540440/709537 )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ildasm /text file.dll | findstr pinvokeimpl
```

If the result is *empty*, pinvoke is **not being used by the dll** (or exe), *otherwise* **it is**.

**N.B.** `ildasm` should come installed with *Visual Studio*, and is easiest to call when using the Visual Studio *Developer Command Prompt*.