# How to use Peverify.exe (PEVerify tool)?

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, unsafe, managed

I saw a couple of post([this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72540750/2719527) specifically) talking about using `peverify.exe` to check whether the .net exe(or dll) contains unsafe code. But no matter what I do I keep getting `File not found or has bad headers` error.

Here are my steps -

1. Open developer power shell for 2022 - Note I did not change the path
   to where the exe is.
2. `peverify <complete path of the dll or exe>`
3. Enter

I keep getting `File not found or has bad headers` error. This should be simple yet there is something I am missing?

---

**Other attempts** with different command with same result is as follows

1. peverify.exe <complete path of the exe/dll> /md /il
2. Tried running the same in Developer Command Prompt for visual studio
   2022

Comment: What version of .NET are you targeting? PEVerify is for .NET Framework 4 (and other Windows-specific versions).

Comment: I am using net5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PEVerify is for the "old" Windows-specific .NET Framework. A newer tool was created for .NET 5+ and .NET Core (although it also works with the old .NET Framework), [ILVerify](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/coreclr/tools/ILVerify/README.md).

To install and run (copying from the README, so this information is here instead of susceptible to link rot):

> ILVerify is published as a global tool package. Install it by running:
>
> ```
> dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ilverify
> ```
>
> Example of use:
>
> ```
> C:\test>dotnet ilverify hello.dll -r "c:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.12\*.dll"
> All Classes and Methods in C:\test\hello.dll Verified.
> ```
>
> Note that ILVerify requires all dependencies of assembly that is being verified to be explicitly specified on the command line.

The package itself is `dotnet-ilverify` on NuGet.org ([here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotnet-ilverify/)).